# Login with Facebook when user is registered, Rails 5, Omniouth with Device

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I have this User model:

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
        user.email = auth.info.email
        user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
        user.fname = auth.info.name   
        user.skip_confirmation!
    end
end

def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    super.tap do |user|
        if data = session["devise.facebook_data"] && 
                  session["devise.facebook_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
            user.email = data["email"] if user.email.blank?
        end
    end
end
```

and this `omniouth_callbacks_controller`:

```
def facebook
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    @user.confirmed_at = Time.now
    if @user.persisted?
        sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
        set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if 
        is_navigational_format?
    else
        session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
        redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
end
```

Everything works, but if user is registered without Facebook and then try to login with Facebook, it is not logged, because there are user row in the table in the database.

I want if user is registered in the site without socials and login with Facebook, to do that and site profile to be connected with Facebook profile.
Is there Omniouth method builtin for this case ?
If not, how to do it ?

Comment: how can you understand with certainty that the 2 user are the same

Comment: With email, because it is unique and it is provided when some1 registering with socials.

Comment: the first problem from this is that Devise will not allow you to register 2 users with the same email, so you need to intercept Devise callback before the user is saved, to get the information from omniauth-facebook. Still what authorization you have with facebook? because we are just talking about obtaining name, surname, email and profile picture.

before doing `if @user.persisted?` you need to check `if User.find_by(email: user.email)`, if that condition render true then run an `update_attributes` on that record to add the name, surname, picture (url)

Comment: Thx, for answer. My logic that I have experience with custom apps and I am using there is this. User makes normal registration in the site. It doesn't matter the email is validated or not for Facebook login. After that he makes login with Facebook. The app first need to check is there Facebook ID (uid) and if there is - login and that's all. If there is no ID, it must find by an email. If there is an email - update and login, if there is not - create and login. I am trying to implement this with Device, Omniouth and Rails 5.

Comment: It must check both ID and email, because. user can't change his Facebok ID, but can change his email. If you login with Facebook and after that change your Facebook email, next time it will not find you. And must be checked the email, because you can register to the site, without Facebook, and if not check the email, app can't connect your account with Facebook account, next time when you try to login with Facebook.